# ContentPage BackgroundColor broken in .net Maui Release Candidate 3?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, maui

In RC1 and RC2 of .net Maui I was able to simply set "BackgroundColor" to "Blue" and that would work. In RC3 it now only displays the default white color each time I run the app for the Windows Machine platform, even if set to Blue.

Is the ContentPage BackgroundColor going to be included in final release of .net Maui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Update VS Preview - Maui GA was just released. ContentPage BackgroundColor works for me there.
- Rebuild Solution to be sure it is clean.
- MAYBE even start a new project, and copy source files over.
- ALSO, What do you have inside the ContentPage? Try setting background color on one or more of the top-level elements in the page, see if that works. Its possible something changed related to how the content fills the page, so perhaps a next-level-down element is now coloring the entire page with its own background.

I tested directly with `MainPage = new MainPage()`.

Question: Did you do `MainPage = new YourContentPage();`, or is the page displayed within AppShell or a NavigationPage?

Comment: Thanks ToolmakerSteve, looks like with rebuild it all works again! The GA is great, looks like I had to replace all my 'Frames' with 'Borders' aswell and it works very well.

Comment: For a fix, I could reset the BackgroundColor using the code behind, but it was not ideal.